How to set how long before the Screensaver kicks in on a Mac and require a password?
I have used a computer for 35+ years and never had any issue for such task for a PC or Mac.
Now I searched for 10 minutes on a Mac with macOS 15.1 and still can't find it.  How is it done?

Isn't it under Lock Screen?

Open System Settings
Navigate to Lock Screen in the side panel and you should see something like this:


"Start Screen Saver when inactive" sets how long until the screensaver kicks in.

"Require password after screen saver begins or display is turned off" is pretty self explanatory.

You may not have the battery/power adapter options if you are not working on a MacBook



ok, if I "navigate" to Lock Screen, I see this. But if I search for Lock or Lock Screen, it doesn't show up. It is just fantastic. I am sure the SVP who plays electric guitar in the keynote event is VERY cool

Something is wrong with your Spotlight search index if searching for "require password" or "lock screen" is not showing results in System Settings.
You might be hitting a bug in 15.1 that has been widely reported, for example here.
The fix is to rebuild your Spotlight index. Try running these commands from Terminal:
sudo mdutil -ai off
sudo mdutil -Ea 
sudo mdutil -ai on 

You need to wait a bit for the index to rebuild, it does not happen instantly. To check on its status, pop open the Spotlight search bar and type any character (even a single . will do fine).


Very good guess as to the actual problem. Looking at the question it’s not clear where OP searched, tips app, online, system settings possibly being new to them since for 30 years it was organized as system preferences and not the new layout originally delivered on iOS.
